# Best practice when you have multiply dropdowns in your form in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When you have multiply dropdowns in a form and want to add data to them, should you go with separate controllers or do you place them all under one?

```
.controller("Controller1", ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.dd1 = [
        { id: 1, type: 'test1' },
        { id: 2, type: 'test2' }
    ];
    $scope.dd2 = [
        { id: 1, type: 'test3' },
        { id: 2, type: 'test4' }
    ];
}]);


OR

.controller("Controller1", ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.dd1 = [
        { id: 1, type: 'test1' },
        { id: 2, type: 'test2' }
    ];

.controller("Controller2", ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.dd2 = [
        { id: 1, type: 'test3' },
        { id: 2, type: 'test4' }
    ];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends.  Angular is all about a Separation of Concerns across controllers.  From the application perspective, if the drop downs are related, I'd advocate keeping them under the same controller.  You don't want to create too many controllers than what is needed within your Angular application as it can quickly complicate application maintainability.

Comment: It´s just a normal form with two textboxes and three dropdowns which I will later post. No directives.
So then I should go with just one controller for this simple form?

Comment: I'd put them in the same controller to begin - if the application ever grows much larger, then I'd refactor my code accordingly.  A single controller makes the development much easier to begin.

Answer (score 0):

It depend of the usage of the dropdown and the number of element there is in.
If it's a important menu or you want to interact more on it (add directives or other element depend of it), you should split them. 
But, if you just want to display data, and add/remove menu tab, let it in the same controller.